# Hibernate java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I encounter this error when deploying to Weblogic9.2

```
����: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [me/irix/spring/datasource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:376)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1620)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2789)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:889)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:328)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:635)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:566)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:136)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:104)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:139)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:320)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:815)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1222)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:433)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67)
    at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:518)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:105)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:821)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:552)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 55 more
```

I have been searching for hours with no luck. I saw some post indicate it may be cause by conflict of hibernate jars, yet I only put in a `hibernate3.jar` from `hibernate-distribution-3.6.10.Final-dist.zip` and with jar inside `lib\required`. Not sure whether it matters, I'm using spring 3.2.8

Could anyone help pointing out the problem?

==========UPDATE==============
here is the xml envolved in the problem:

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop      
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd            
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxoolDataSource">
        <property name="alias">
        <value>spring</value>
        </property>
        <property name="driver">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="driverUrl">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytable?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
        <value>myusername</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
        <value>mypassword</value>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="lazy">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>  
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>

            <prop key="connection.useUnicode">true</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">GBK</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">GBK</prop>
            <prop key="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.ProxoolConnectionProvider</prop>

            <!--  <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>  -->
        </props>  
    </property> 

  </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

I follow @chrylis 's suggestion and see this:
[image]

it throws error when execute line 526 `mbd.getFactoryBeanName()`

Comment: @chrylis I have added the xml content

Comment: Please post your entity class \

Comment: @BalajiReddy which entity class are you refering to ?

Comment: The entity class has nothing to do with it. Please run this in a debugger and find which class Spring is trying to instantiate with reflection.

Comment: @BalajiReddy I kind of don't think it have something to do with pojo, it's still in sessionfactory part.

Comment: The session factory failed only when it instate the entity.

Comment: BalajiReddy it's reseanable deduction, I follow @chrylis 's suggestion and see it did throw exception when initializing sessionFactory